# Nginx - long response times when using sub_filter

Tags: nginx

We use nginx to create a protocol break between our customers and our infrastructure.

A constraint of the infrastructure obliges us to make modifications of the answers provided by the infrastructure via the use of sub_filter.

We're seeing significant delays in the responses, and we'd like to know if we've configured :

- response modifications
- cache deactivation (we don't want large files to be stored on the nginx server when there are PUTs).

Below is the specific nginx configuration for this site:

```
map $status $auth_service {
  401  'service uri="$http_X_OAPI_Forwarded_Proto://$http_X_OAPI_Forwarded_Host$http_X_OAPI_Forwarded_Prefix"';
}


server {
   listen 10.222.22.222:443;
   server_name service.monsite.fr;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/service.access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/service.error.log;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/service.monsite.fr.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/service.monsite.fr.key;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    proxy_pass https://172.10.0.9:12665;
    sub_filter_types *;
    sub_filter 'https://internalurl.monsite.fr:13080' 'https://externalurl.monsite.fr';
    sub_filter 'https://internalurl.monsite.fr:13080' 'https://externalurl.monsite.fr';
   }

}
```

If you have any other recommendations/comments on configuration, please let us know.

Best regards,

Comment: Do you really have two identical `sub_filter` statements?

Comment: Ah yes... Could it be a problem ?